# Map a javascript array to html table

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to create a function that maps a grid, represented as a nested array, to a html table.

For example take list:

```
[
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d', 'e', 'f'],
    ['f', 'g', 'h']
]
```

and alter html table to show:

```
a b c 
d e f
f g h
```

Assume table size predetermined and list matches the dimensions.

So something that completes:

```
table border="1">
<tr>
<td>row 1, cell 1</td>
<td>row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>


<script>
update = [['a','b'],['c','d']]

function updateTableHTML(myArray) {
  // maps the list onto the existing table
}

updateTableHTML(update)
</script>
```

Comment: please show us the code you have developed so far

Comment: [Here is the link to similar post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164655/generate-html-table-from-2d-javascript-array

Comment: Thanks, but my problem requires updating the existing table rather than creating a new one based on the list. I'll add my code

Comment: @sock Okay good deal, be sure to also include in your question that this is a requirement.

Comment: Use a templating language such as Handlebars.

Comment: I keep getting amazed by questions where the poster did absolutely nothing to solve the question himself AND where the question looks like it comes out of a course AND the great lengths that some users here will still go to post an awesome answer (props to the user that did)

Comment: @user1914292 Don't blame him, everyone has been a noob at some point of their programming experience (of course this doesn't give you the right to post zero-effort questions, but still). Btw I keep getting amazed too ahahah.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use the [`Array.prototype.forEach` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), or a simple for loop. You just have to **step throught each component of your bidimensional array and create a `<td>`** element inside your table.

By the way, I don't feel comfortable with the assumption that the table already has got the right number of rows and columns (i.e. the `update` array fits the dimensions of the table): it's better to re-build the `<tbody>` from scratch to avoid any error and create a more flexible function. So let's assume an initial situation like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody id="your-table-body-id">
        <!-- whatever... -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

#### Old school `for` loops

Here's an example with simple `for` loops:

```
function updateTableHTML(myArray) {
    var tableBody = document.getElementById("your-table-body-id"),
        newRow, newCell;

    // Reset the table
    tableBody.innerHTML = "";

    // Build the new table
    for (var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        newRow = document.createElement("tr");
        tableBody.appendChild(newRow);

        if (myArray[i] instanceof Array) {
            for (var j=0; j < myArray[i].length; j++) {
                newCell = document.createElement("td");
                newCell.textContent = update[i][j];
                newRow.appendChild(newCell);
            }
        } else {
            newCell = document.createElement("td");
            newCell.textContent = myArray[i];
            newRow.appendChild(newCell);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Fancy `Array` methods

And here's an example with the `Array.prototype.forEach` method:

```
function updateTableHTML(myArray) {
    var tableBody = document.getElementById("your-table-body-id");

    // Reset the table
    tableBody.innerHTML = "";

    // Build the new table
    myArray.forEach(function(row) {
        var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
        tableBody.appendChild(newRow);

        if (row instanceof Array) {
            row.forEach(function(cell) {
                var newCell = document.createElement("td");
                newCell.textContent = cell;
                newRow.appendChild(newCell);
            });
        } else {
            newCell = document.createElement("td");
            newCell.textContent = row;
            newRow.appendChild(newCell);
        }
    });
}
```

#### Notes

Be aware that the `Array.prototype.forEach` method may not be supported in every browser (i.e. Internet Explorer < 9). The `for` method looks easier and more comprehensible to me (although I'm not sure which one is faster), but that's your choice.

Also, in case you were wondering: I'm checking `if (row instanceof Array)` because in a situation like the following:

```
update = ["a", "b", "c"];
```

I am assuming you want a result like this:

```
a
b
c
```

and therefore you'll have to check if the value is an array before looping again and building the cells of each row.

Comment: ver newCell = document.createElement("td"); 
that should be var ...
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
var a = [
   ['a', 'b', 'c'],
   ['d', 'e', 'f'],
   ['f', 'g', 'h']
];
var html = "<table>";
for(var i in a){
    html += "<tr>";
      for(var j in a[i])
        html += "<td>"+a[i][j]+"</td>";
    html += "</tr>";
}

html += "</table>";
document.write(html);
```

Comment: Your answer to this question which has multiple duplicates is just a code block with no explanation. Would you be able to elaborate / explain further what you've posted?

Comment: I did not detect comments,when writing

Comment: Building HTML as a string is never a good idea.

Comment: "Building HTML as a string is never a good idea", Why? I would say most of the web is made this way. HTML pages as strings.

Answer (score 0):

#### Simple solution

Since you say you're absolutely sure the dimensions all match up, then you can simply do

```
function updateTableHTML(update) {
    var cells = table.querySelectorAll('td');                       // get cells
    update = Array.concat.apply([], update);                        // flatten array
    update . forEach(function(v, i) { cells[i].textContent = v; }); // update
}
```

`cells` is just a list of all the `<td>` elements (flat).

We flatten the `update` nested array using `Array#concat` with `apply`. `Array.concat.apply([], [[1, 2], [3, 4]])` turns into `[].concat([1, 2], [3,4])`, which yields `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Now we have two parallel one-dimensional arrays, so we just need to loop through the `update` array and set the content of the corresponding element (cell) to each value.