# JavaScript 2D array to table, how to target the table to a div?

Tags: javascript, html, multidimensional-array

JavaScript 2D array to table, how to target the table to a div?
The following link talked about create a table from 2D array.
[Generate HTML table from 2D JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164655/generate-html-table-from-2d-javascript-array)
The table was created very well, but the table always shows up at the end of the page.
How to make the table show up in a div?

```
function createTable(tableData) {
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');

  tableData.forEach(function(rowData) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');

    rowData.forEach(function(cellData) {
      var cell = document.createElement('td');
      cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
      row.appendChild(cell);
    });

    tableBody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tableBody);
  document.body.appendChild(table);
}

createTable([["row 1, cell 1", "row 1, cell 2"], ["row 2, cell 1", "row 2, cell 2"]]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you had

```
<div id="MyTargetDiv"></div>
```

then you need to change

```
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

to

```
document.getElementById("MyTargetDiv").appendChild(table);
```

Comment: Just a cautionary word, be sure to read/understand the code you're putting into your website