# JavaScript/jQuery Create HTML from Delimited List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I know I am supposed to have a go at the code so I can post my effort here but I've tried a few times to do this and my code is a mess.   Apologies.

I have a tab delimited string and I want to convert this to a HTML table with 3 columns.   So if the string has 6 values then I would like this to be 2 rows.  For example:

```
aa | bb | cc | dd | ee | ff
```

would become

```
aa | bb | cc
dd | ee | ff
```

Is there a way to do this with JavaScript or jQuery?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please post your messy code, we're not going to write it for you. Convert the string to an array with `split()`. Loop through the array in increments of 3, and then add elements `i`, `i+1`, and `i+2` as cells in the table, and start a new row for each group.

Comment: If my code was anywhere near presentable then I would but it was so far away from being correct I felt it would have been a hindrance/distraction, rather than a help.  Thanks to everyone who has posted solutions

Comment: They should be condemned for letting you get away with such an incomplete question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps. You can find the comments in the code below.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 var strColumn = "aa | bb | cc | dd | ee | ff";

 var table = $("<table/>"); //Create new table element
 $.each(strColumn.split("|"), function (i, val){
  if (i == 0 || i % 3 == 0) row = $("<tr/>"); //Create new row after every 3 columns
  row.append($("<td>" + val.trim() + "</td>")); //Create table column and append to row
  table.append (row); //Append row to table
 });
 $("body").append(table); //Append table to body element
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use some simple logic to achieve this with `jQuery` as shown below.

```js
var input = "aa | bb | cc | dd | ee | ff | aaa | fsf";

//Frmat the input
input = input.split("|").map(function(text) {
  return text.trim();
});


var MAX_COL_COUNT = 3,
  table = $("#table"),
  cellCounter = 0,
  rowCounter = 0;

//Add into a table with tr and td
input.forEach(function(text) {
  if (cellCounter == MAX_COL_COUNT || cellCounter == 0) {
    table.append("<tr></tr>");
    rowCounter++;
    cellCounter = 0;
  }

  table.find("tr").eq(rowCounter - 1).append("<td>" + text + "</td>");
  cellCounter++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table id="table">

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make an array from the string with split();
use this:

```
var str = "aa | bb | cc | dd | ee | ff";
var array = str.split("|");
```

This wil give you an array like this:

```
[aa,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff]
```

Next we are going to split this array every 3 items to make a 2 dimensional array.

```
var str = "aa | bb | cc | dd | ee | ff";
var array = str.split("|");

var 2dArray = [];
var  count = 0;
var arr = [];
for(var i in array){
    arr.push(array[i]);
    count++;
    if(count > 2){
       2dArray.push(arr);
       arr = [];
       count = 0;
    }
}
```

Now we have a two dimensional array. You can easily parse it to a table. For example check this out: [Generate HTML table from 2D JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164655/generate-html-table-from-2d-javascript-array)

NOTE: I have came up with this out of my head. So maybe it needs some finetuning, but it will give you an idea.