# React multi array to table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array with multiple depths of each column i want to represent as a table. The column of the table have to be participant, category, cards, comment.

```
participant_data = [
    '#1',
    [
        ['not set #0', ['card1', 'A very large title title tile1', 'A very large title title tile5', 'A very large title title tile4', 'A very large title title tile6', 'A very large title title tile7', 'A very large title title tile8', 'A very large title title tile10']],
        ['not set #1', ['A very large title title tile2', 'A very large title title tile9']],
        ['not set #2', ['A very large title title tile3']],
        ['name1', ['card1', 'A very large title title tile1', 'A very large title title tile3', 'A very large title title tile2', 'A very large title title tile4', 'A very large title title tile5', 'A very large title title tile6', 'A very large title title tile7']],
        ['name2', ['A very large title title tile8', 'A very large title title tile9', 'A very large title title tile10']],
        ['name21', ['card1', 'A very large title title tile1']],
        ['name22', ['A very large title title tile2', 'A very large title title tile4', 'A very large title title tile5', 'A very large title title tile9', 'A very large title title tile10']],
        ['name23', ['A very large title title tile3', 'A very large title title tile6', 'A very large title title tile7', 'A very large title title tile8']],
        ['test merge', ['card1', 'A very large title title tile1', 'A very large title title tile2']],
        ['merge2', ['card1', 'A very large title title tile1', 'A very large title title tile2']],
        ['cat1', ['card1', 'A very large title title tile1', 'A very large title title tile2', 'A very large title title tile3', 'A very large title title tile4', 'A very large title title tile5', 'A very large title title tile6']],
        ['cat2', ['A very large title title tile7', 'A very large title title tile9', 'A very large title title tile10']],
        ['cat3', ['A very large title title tile8']]
    ],
    'comment '
]
```

Note that I can change the structure of the data. As you see I can have many participants. Each participant has many categories and each category has many cards. I want a way to display it which is obvious which card is in each category.

Comment: So which issue have you faced when attempting this?

Comment: i cannot find a way to do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate HTML table from 2D JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164655/generate-html-table-from-2d-javascript-array)

Comment: no, it has be a row for each participant bu something like sub row for each category and cards that belong to those category

Comment: You can nest tables inside tables in HTML. I suggest you start with a plain HTML example to get it the way you want. Then you can try to render the same structure with react. It is better if you include your attempts with code snippets in the question. Otherwise it looks a bit like you're just asking for others to do the work for you. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and in particular `Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first.`.

Answer (score 0):

i Changed the data from array to object and here is the solution I found

```
{sortedData.map((item, index, array) => (
                            <tr key={item.no}>
                                {index === 0 || item.no !== array[index - 1].no ? (
                                    <td rowSpan={array.filter((el) => el.no === item.no).length}>
                                        {item.no}
                                    </td>
                                ) : null}
                                <td>{item.category}</td>
                                <td>
                                    {Array.isArray(item.cards) ? (
                                        <ul>
                                            {item.cards.map((desc, index) => (
                                                <li key={index}>{desc}</li>
                                            ))}
                                        </ul>
                                    ) : (
                                        item.cards
                                    )}
                                </td>
                                {index === 0 || item.no !== array[index - 1].no ? (
                                    <td rowSpan={array.filter((el) => el.no === item.no).length}>
                                        {item.comment}
                                    </td>
                                ) : null}
                            </tr>
                        ))}
```